# Convert JSON API Requests response to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I'm struggling to convert a JSON API response into a `pandas Dataframe` object. I've read answers to similar questions/documentation, but nothing has helped.

Below is part of the function I'm trying to create:

Below is the response when calling the API:

```
{
    'applicantId': '1006086625',
    'refApplicantId': None,
    'CompanyTaxStatus': {
        'RFC': 'XXXX000000X00',
        'PayingTax': 'POSITIVO',
        'ReportDataUpdateDate': '2023-08-02T00: 00: 00'
    },
    'CompanyObligationsList': None,
    'Success': True,
    'message': None
}{
    "applicantId": "1006086625",
    "refApplicantId": null,
    "CompanyTaxStatus": {
        "RFC": "XXXX000000X00",
        "PayingTax": "POSITIVO",
        "ReportDataUpdateDate": "2023-08-02T00:00:00"
    },
    "CompanyObligationsList": null,
    "Success": true,
    "message": null
}
```

What I would like to get is only the info from "CompanyTaxStatus" into a `Pandas Dataframe`.

```
def get_Company_Tax_Status(company_id):

    url = f"https://service.com/apiservice.svc/GetCompanyTaxStatus?taxId={company_id}"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'apiId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'apiKey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
    }


    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print("JSON Response: \n", data)

        df = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')

        print(df.head())  #

    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}")

    print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_Company_Tax_Status(company_id):

    url = f"https://service.com/apiservice.svc/GetCompanyTaxStatus?taxId={company_id}"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'apiId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'apiKey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print("JSON Response: \n", data)

        # Extract "CompanyTaxStatus" and normalize the nested JSON structure
        company_tax_status_data = data.get("CompanyTaxStatus", {})
        df = pd.json_normalize(company_tax_status_data)

        print(df.head())  # Display the DataFrame

    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}")

    print(response.text)

# Example usage:
get_Company_Tax_Status("your_company_id_here")
```